# How do I modify a file in a jar file using ANT?

Tags: ant, jar

I need to update an XML file that's inside of a jar file using ANT. I have to search for a string in the file and replace it with another value if that string exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A crude approach. Unzip the `jar` file, use the `replace` ant task, zip the files again and put the `jar` file back.

- [Task: `copy`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)
- [Task: `unzip`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html)
- [Task: `replace`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html)
- [Task: `zip`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html)
- [Task: `move`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html)