# Can ant replace text in files inside a jar/ear/war?

Tags: java, ant

I want to build my ear file once and then use ant to change some settings in application.xml, property files etc.

Is there way to do this with ant?

[edit] Just found this

[How do I modify a file in a jar file using ANT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737560/how-do-i-modify-a-file-in-a-jar-file-using-ant)

Comment: AFAIK, no. Replace task works on directories. Could you unzip, replace and re-zip?

Comment: Does the update option work for what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059046/ant-ear-update-without-full-exploding-ear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you can modify a file inside your jar or ear is to use the `<unzip>` task, use the `<replace>` task to modify the fields in the file, and then rezip the file back up with either the `<zip>` or `<jar>/<ear>` task.

There are several ways you can handle this without having to unzip and rezip your ear/jar/war files:

- The preferred method is to setup your application server, so it can find your properties outside of the ear itself. It is also possible to configure the `application.xml` file not to use relative directories when specifying locations instead of specifying locations from the root of the machine. By removing embedded environment information from your ear, you can use the same earfile on all of your environments.
- We, unfortunately, are unable to do the above and must provide separate ear files for each environment. We use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) as our continuous build server. When Jenkins does our builds, we build multiple ears, one for each environment, at the same time. This way, as we move from Dev to QA to STAGE to Production, we can at least refer to the same build number. We compile once, then use the [AntContrib `<foreach>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) to ear up the earfile with the correct properties file settings and the correct `application.xml` file. We use `<filterset>` in our `<copy>` task to modify the properties and `application.xml` as we build the ear.

Comment: Thanks, we're using jenkins too and have considered building 3 or 4 ear files but was hoping for another solution. BTW the build pipline plugin's pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<zip destfile="tmp.jar" >
  <zipfileset src="lib/myjar.jar" excludes="org/example/My*.class" />
  <zipfileset dir="bin" includes="org/example/My*.class"  />
</zip>
<move file="tmp.jar" tofile="lib/myjar.jar"/>
```

In this example we create a tmp.jar using myjar.jar as the source but excluding all classees beginning My in the org/example directory. We then add our new version in from the bin directory. We then replace the jar file with our new version.