# Ant Nested Update

Tags: java, ant, jboss, war, ear

This is a follow up question related to my question from yesterday:
[Ant Ear Update Without Full Exploding Ear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059046/ant-ear-update-without-full-exploding-ear/12064022#12064022)

I'm using Ant 1.8.2 and am able to update files in an ear, using the example I made in the provided link above.

I have a war file inside my ear file, and I'm hoping to see if there is a way to do a nested update (e.g. update a file in the war that is in the ear).

My other option is to extract the war, update the war, then update the ear with the updated war. If there is a way to do the nested update, I think it would save me time, as my war file is pretty big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is my alternative approach POC, in case anyone is interested. I will use this if we cannot find a "nested" update.

```
<property name="ear.file1"          value="file1.ear"/>
<property name="war.file1"          value="war1.war"/>
<property name="war.file"           value="war.war"/>
<property name="war.file.backup"    value="warBk.war"/>
<property name="text.file1"         value="1.txt"/>
<property name="text.file2"         value="2.txt"/>
<property name="xml.application1"   value="application.xml"/>

<target name="clean">
    <delete file="${ear.file1}"/>
    <delete file="${war.file}"/>
    <delete file="${war.file.backup}"/>
</target>

<target name="run">

    <!-- Our war file contains 1.txt, allows us add 2.txt and verify updates properly -->
    <copy file="${war.file1}" tofile="${war.file}"/>

    <!-- simple ear that will be updated -->
    <ear earfile="${ear.file1}" appxml="${xml.application1}">
        <fileset dir="." includes="${text.file1}"/>
        <fileset dir="." includes="${war.file}"/>
    </ear>  

    <!-- Backup war, for comparision purposes -->
    <move file="${war.file}" tofile="${war.file.backup}" overwrite="true" />

    <!-- Extact the war we just added -->
    <unzip dest="." src="${ear.file1}" overwrite="true" >
        <patternset>
            <include name="${war.file}" />
        </patternset>
    </unzip>

    <!-- Update the war by adding a file -->
    <war destfile="${war.file}" update="true">
        <fileset dir="." includes="${text.file2}"/>
    </war>

    <!-- Update the ear with our updated war -->
    <ear earfile="${ear.file1}" appxml="${xml.application1}" update="true">
        <fileset dir="." includes="${war.file}"/>
    </ear>  
</target>

<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
```